# Extract numeric value and specific characters from a file name string

Tags: r, string

I don't quite understand regular expressions yet, and for this project I don't have time to learn it (but intending to ASAP). Say I have these file names as strings:

```
string <- c("2019data/ABC19_XY_10001/finit1/ABC19_XY_10001_FAST (1).csv", 
            "2019data/ABC19_XY_2145/finit2/ABC19_XY_2154_GRABBER (1).csv")
```

For this example, I want to extract *only* the number after the underscore, i.e., `10001` and `2145`, and the final word, i.e., `FAST` and `GRABBER` and paste them together like so: `10001_FAST` and `2145_GRABBER`. How would I do that?

**Edit**: The file structure is almost always like this, except the numeric value can be any number of digits, and the word at the end can be as long as whoever named the file.

Comment: One example isn't much to generalize off of. Is it always exactly 5 digits, then an underscore, and then exactly 4 letters? Or is the number the only pure number surrounded by underscores? Is it always 10 characters right before the only space in the file name? Maybe you could give us a few more strings illustrating the variety of what you want to match, and a little more description to help identify the patterns

Comment: Give us some more detail. Can we expext those sub strings to always appear at certain positions? Extracting those based on the patterns "10001" and "FAST" does not make any sense. It would be easier to write `paste0("10001", "_", "FAST")` instead.

Comment: No regular expression is required. Simply type "10001_FAST". Or formulate the question more exactly.

Comment: Sorry, yes, it is not always exactly 5 digits, but there's always an underscore after it, and then however long the word is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With such little detail who knows if this will work on a second case, but it does work on the lone example provided:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(string, pattern = "(?<=_)\\d+_[A-Z]+")
# [1] "10001_FAST"
```

Explanation:

- `(?<=_)` look for an underscore, but don't include it in the match,
- `\\d+` then one or more digits,
- `_` then an underscore,
- `[A-Z]+` then one or more capital letters

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked after I edited it slightly: `str_extract(string, pattern = "(?<=_)\\d+_\\w+")`. That's exactly what I needed and your explanations of what each of them do is very helpful. Apologies for the lack of detail, I mistakenly thought I had provided enough.

Comment: Okay, do be a bit careful with `\\w`, it will match letters, numbers, and underscores. If you want just letters but case doesn't matter, then `"(?<=_)\\d+_[A-Za-z]+"` might be safer.

Comment: I tried it and that only gave me the first digit in the number and the first letter of word?

Comment: Works fine for me on the 2 examples provided. Though if there's an earlier pattern match in some string, regex will take the first match.

Comment: Ah, okay, that's probably why. Again I greatly appreciate your help and thanks for being kind.

Comment: Yeah, that's why more explanation and examples are helpful. At first I thought to do the pattern `[numbers]_[letters]`, but that would match `19_XY` in your file names. That's why I added the check for the preceding underscore that stays unmatched. But if your file names might have other things that you don't want that happen to match the pattern, they might get caught up. We could potentially add a space after matched part of the pattern, but maybe they don't all have those spaces? Maybe space or `.` after the pattern? Hard to say without more examples.